# nodejs TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js, cookie, express, type-error

Когда я принимаю get запрос, мне нужно просмотреть значение main.cookies[cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).sessionid]. Но в консоли выдает ошибку TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Помогите с этим, пожалуйста!

---

@RTK Дело в том, что ругается именно на cookie.parse и тд. Я пробовал и .toString(), и String(cookie.parse..). А вот console.log отлично выводит.

```js
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  var main = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/main.json', 'utf8');
  delete main.cookies[cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).sessionid];
  let expires = new Date()
  expires.setTime(expires.getTime()-(1));
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/main.json', JSON.stringify(main, null, '  '), 'utf8');
  res.cookie('sessionid', cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).sessionid, {"expires":expires});
  res.sendFile('./html/index.html', {"root":__dirname});
});
```

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Судя по ошибке, в какой-то момент вы обращаетесь к переменой, которая не определена.

Comment: @RTK Дело в том, что ругается именно на cookie.parse и тд. Я пробовал и .toString(), и String(cookie.parse..). А вот console.log отлично выводит.

Comment: @thenevikatyt и какое значение console.log() oтлично выводит? и что вы собственно пытаетесь вывести в консоль? чтобы исключить ошибку, предлагаю обернуть третью строчку вашего примера так: if (req.headers && req.headers.cookie) { delete main.cookies[cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).sessionid]; } else { console.log('oh sh...'); }

Comment: @thenevikatyt  хреновню сгородил) во второй строчке переменная main имеет тип данных "строка". а у строки вы не можете удалить поле cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во второй строчке переменная main имеет тип данных "строка". а у строки вы не можете удалить поле cookies.
Полученную строку надо преобразовать к объекту:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  var main = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/main.json', 'utf8') );
  ...
});
```

Обратите внимание, что `JSON.parse` может выкинуть ошибку, если передаваемая на вход строка не соответствует формату `json`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это и вправду работает. Просто у меня везде стояло через require, а здесь я тестировал чтение utf-8. Ещё раз спасибо!)